# cannot be redefined on prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I'm pretty new on prolog and haven't quite understood some of its logic. I got this code for list in prolog:

```
guardians([starlord, gamora, rocket, groot, drax]).
avengers([rogers, stark, banner, thor, hawkeye]).
xmen([xavier, logan, summers, grey, beast]).

leader([starlord, rogers, xavier]).
incharge([gamora, stark, logan]).
members([rocket, groot, drax, banner, thor, hawkeye, summers, grey, beast]).

group1(guardians).
group2(avengers).
group3(xmen).
rank1(leaders).
rank2(incharge).
rank3(members).

member(X,[X|T]).
member(X,[H|T]):-
   member(X,T).

is_member(X,Y):-
   guardians(A),    member(X,A), group1(Y);
   avengers(B),     member(X,B), group2(Y);
   xmen(C),         member(X,C), group3(Y).

is_positioned(X,Y):-
   leaders(A),  member(X,A), rank1(Y);
   incharge(B),     member(X,B), rank2(Y);
   members(C),      member(X,C), rank3(Y).

has_position_in(X,Y,Z):-
   is_member(X,Z),
   is_positioned(X,Y).
```

I got an error:

```
error: C:/sample.pl:16: native code procedure member/2 cannot be redefined (ignored)
```

Which I think refers to this one:

```
member(X,[X|T]).
member(X,[H|T]):-
   member(X,T).
```

What does that indicate and how to avoid future instances?

Comment: Your Prolog system apparently already **provides** `member/2`, and you cannot redefine it. Either *omit* your own definition (thus, using the system-provided one instead, which may be even better than what you wrote), or *rename* your predicate to avoid this conflict.

Comment: that makes sense. thanks a lot.